# Items not being appended to list

Tags: python, list, append, python-3.8

This program is not saving the things append in the list.  When it come out it do not store the number that was put in the list.

```
def marks():
    
    mark=int(input("ENTER YOUR MARKS = "))
    
    T=int(input("ENTER TOTAL MARKS"))
    
    hold=[11]#TO STORE MARKS SCORED
    
    total=[16]#TO STORE TOTAL MARKS
    
    hold.append(mark)
    
    total.append(T)
    
    p=(sum(hold)/sum(total))*100
    
    print('YOUR AVERAGE PERCENTAGE = ' ,p,"\n" ,
          hold, total)
```

I want this code to store the values that are appended in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring list everytime,You need to declare list in global scope so that data in it does not reset everytime you call function marks()

```
hold=[11]#TO STORE MARKS SCORED
total=[16]#TO STORE TOTAL MARKS 
def marks():
    mark=int(input("ENTER YOUR MARKS = "))
    T=int(input("ENTER TOTAL MARKS"))
    hold.append(mark)
    total.append(T)
    p=(sum(hold)/sum(total))*100
    print('YOUR AVERAGE PERCENTAGE = ' ,p,"\n" ,hold, total)
```